# Test React on Chrome browser

Tags: reactjs

How can I see what I´m building on my Chrome browser?
I know how to see PHP through local server, see HTML website through normal ways and with Gulp but can´t seem to understand this.

Comment: What have you tried, you can't simply just write React code and no use something to view it.  Have you tried the samples on React site?  Have you looked on GitHub for react samples there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look into `create-react-app`, it comes handy with a few things that are already prebuilt `https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app`

Here's a tutorial on it: https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/learning-react-with-create-react-app-part-1-a12e1833fdc

You can load the build from your project on 'create-react-app' into your PHP project.